How to use a ToolBar selector in a Pane
Assuming any theme such as modena, caspian, jametro etc.
How to get the declarations or contents of a selector,
example "tool-bar:vertical" and apply it to any Node
Now inside Pane, how do I place this selector?

In Caspian.css the tool-bar:vertical selector has this content
However, this solution does not meet the need.
because you need to consider the Theme being used
 String ss = """
              -fx-background: derive(-fx-base,-20%);
             -fx-background-color:
                 linear-gradient(to right, derive(-fx-base,-30%), derive(-fx-base,-60%)),
                 linear-gradient(to right, derive(-fx-base,65%) 2%, derive(-fx-base,-20%) 95%);
             -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 0 1;
             -fx-background-radius: 0 ;
             -fx-padding: 0.833em 0.416667em 0.833em 0.416667em; /* 10 5 10 5 */
             -fx-spacing: 0.333em; /* 4 */
             -fx-alignment: TOP_LEFT;
                """;
        
pane.setStyle(ss);

Tried this
.tool-bar-pane {
     @extend .tool-bar:vertical;
}

pane.setStyle("tool-bar-pane");
but it doesn't allow @extend
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class PaneTheme extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      
        setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN);
        // setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_MODENA);
        // others
        // setUserAgentStylesheet(...);
        
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        
        
        pane.getStyleClass().setAll("tool-bar:vertical");
             
        // tool-bar:vertical Modena.css
        String ss = """
                     -fx-background-color:
                            -fx-outer-border,
                            linear-gradient(to right, derive(-fx-base,0%) 0%, derive(-fx-base,10%) 50%, derive(-fx-base,0%) 100%);
                        -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 0 1;
                        -fx-padding: 0.5em 0.416667em 0.5em 0.416667em; /* 6 5 6 5 */
                        -fx-spacing: 0.333em; /* 4 */
                        -fx-alignment: TOP_LEFT;
                    """;
        
        
        // tool-bar Caspian.css
        ss =   """  
             -fx-background: derive(-fx-base,-20%);
            -fx-background-color:
                linear-gradient(to right, derive(-fx-base,-30%), derive(-fx-base,-60%)),
                linear-gradient(to right, derive(-fx-base,65%) 2%, derive(-fx-base,-20%) 95%);
            -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 0 1;
            -fx-background-radius: 0 ;
            -fx-padding: 0.833em 0.416667em 0.833em 0.416667em; /* 10 5 10 5 */
            -fx-spacing: 0.333em; /* 4 */
            -fx-alignment: TOP_LEFT;
               """;
        
       // pane.setStyle(".tool-bar:vertical");
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Pane change Seletor");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


Not sure I understand the question, but probably you should use an external style sheet (which you can define as a data: url in code if you need). Inline styles can only be applied to the node on which you call setStyle(...).

If it is not possible to use a selector from one node in another, then there must be a way to obtain the contents of the "tool-bar" selector?

It's not really clear what you're asking. There is no selector in the code you posted. You can only use selectors in external CSS. You can navigate the scene graph in Java in the usual way using getChildren() etc. to find the contents of a node. In external CSS, you can use the syntax for CSS selectors to get the descendants of a matched node, in various ways. I don't think setting a class to tool-bar:vertical will work as the :vertical syntax is for a pseudoclass called vertical.

JavaFX CSS reference is here.  There is no reference there to @extend, which means that approach is unlikely to work.  According, this @extend is not standard CSS, it is SASS (a CSS preprocessor).  You could (probably) use a SASS preprocessor to generate CSS usable by JavaFX.  I don't advise it.  The standard stylesheets are not SASS, so I don't know if it would work for your use-case in any case.

Though this seems a very odd approach., I think you are looking for a solution as below. i.e, to reuse the existing style declarations on a custom node.
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getStyleClass().add("tool-bar");
pane.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("vertical"), true);

